# Is it possible to run a predefined script in pycharm debugger?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using the pycharm debugger quite often, and every time I stop at a break point, I'm running the same thing, e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Is it possible to run this predefined script everytime?

Comment: But you run this in a python console, or in the debugger?

Comment: in the debugger python console. adding it under settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->console->Python console did not help